# Most fitting View/Layout for placing several text- and image views inside, XML for Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, uiscrollview, android-relativelayout

So I have this ScrollView inside which I have a RelativeLayout on one of my views on my Android app. Inside the RelativeLayout I already have a TableLayout that I'm using, and above it I want; 2 different text views (one header and one longer text, and I want the header to be placed on top of the longer bit of text) aswell as an ImageView that I want to be placed to the right of the 2 TextViews, and I want all 3 views to be placed on a differently colored background than the other stuff on the ScrollView such as the TableLayout for example.

I tried putting another RelativeLayout inside the ScrollView but it tells me ScrollView can only host one direct child, so that didn't really pan out. What would the most fitting way to accomplish this? Because I want this 3-view-background-thingie to scroll with the TableLayout and all the other stuff on the view.

As always, thankful for any answers or tips!

(My design kinda looks like this at the moment, schematically;)

```
<Container (that doesn't scroll)/>
<ScrollView
    <RelativeLayout
        *Alot of stuff here, such as a TableLayout for example
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put everything in your `RelativeLayout`

```
<ScrollView
    <RelativeLayout
        <LinearLayout>
            <TextView>
            </TextView>
            <TextView>
            </TextView>
            <ImageView>
            </ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TableLayout>
        </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This way, the only child is the RelativeLayout, the others being children of the RelativeLayout.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! Okay, so I put all the two text views + the image view in the linear layout, or? Because as I mentioned, I want them all to be on the same background.

Comment: I've edited my answer but yes, as long as the `ScrollView` really only has one child, it's fine!

Comment: Okay fine, thank you for the answer! Will try that now